# letztlich und letztendlich

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen letztlich und letztendlich, hinsichtlich des Sinnes?

zum Beispiel

> Dass sein Buch verrissen wurden, hat ihm letztlich einen Denkzettel
> verpasst.

und

> Dass sein Buch verrissen wurden, hat ihm letztendlich einen Denkzettel
> verpasst.

Für mich sind beide perfekte Synonyme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nein, es gibt keinen Unterschied. *Letztlich* und *letztendlich* sind perfekte Synonyme.